# Force pytest to mark failed tests with F instead of a dot

Tags: python, pytest

My pytest provides only dots in different colors at output. I'd like to have letters instead since colors are not visible when droped to file.

`BAD:  test.py ..........`
`GOOD: test.py ...F..FF..`

How to fix this?

Comment: IMHO your GOOD version is how pytest works by default (at least in the latest version) so as per the answer check for any customization of yours.

Comment: Add the output of `pytest -vvvv --collect-only | grep plugins` to the question. If you see no plugins that could affect the output, check for custom plugins in conftests, e.g. run `pytest --noconftest` and see whether the output normalizes.

Answer (score 0):

I read the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org) but could not find any reference to this behavior, or any kind of parametrization that would do this.

Are you sure you do not have an inopportune [pytest customization](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html) or plugin ?

Otherwise, if you redirect result to a file to read it without colors afterwards, you can try some nice pytest plugins which improve readability of the output like [pytest-spec](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-spec/), or even make an html report like [pytest-html](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html/).